# Django sessions between views not working

Tags: python, ajax, django, session

I'm unable to access variable the variable solo in my coordinates function. **The debug statement "solo used:" outputs "none".** What do I need to do to make this work? Thanks a mil for your thoughts.

in views.py

```
def go(request):
  print "go executing"
  lat = request.GET.get('latitude', None)
  lng = request.GET.get('longitude', None)
  if not lat or not lng:
    print "ERROR: BAD URL PARAMETERS"
  # call the dronekit module we wrote before
  solo = drone.drone()
  print "solo instantiated: ", solo
  solo.takeoff()
  solo.flyTo(lat,lng, 60)
  resp = "Arrived and landed. <br> <a href=/rtl>Return Home</a>"
  request.session['solo'] = "hello"
  return HttpResponse(resp)

def coordinates(request):
  #print "Request: ", request
  #if request.method == 'GET':
  solo = request.session.get('solo')
  print "solo used: ", solo

  # print "made it to views.py, and lat: ", solo.getlat(), ". lng: ", solo.getlng() 
  #print "lat: ", lat, ". lng: ", lng
  #lat1 = fly_drone.getlat()
  #lat2 = fly_drone.getlng()
  #print "lat1: ", lat1, ". lat2: ", lat2
  return HttpResponse('check')
```

Note that I'm calling coordinates from map.js via ajax:

```
function refreshData()
{
  x = 5;
  setTimeout(refreshData, x*1000);
  console.log("refreshing now");
  $.ajax({
    url: '/coordinates/',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data){
      //alert(data);
    },
    failure: function(data){
      //alert('Got an error dude');
    }
  })
```

Note that I do have session serializer on in settings.py:

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
...
MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]



 INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'skyway_app'
    ]
```

Comment: Do you have `SessionMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE ` / `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES `?

Comment: Hey Raz, yeah I do..

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, [read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/):

1. Ensure that `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` 
   is in your `MIDDLEWARE` in your settings.
2. Make sure your session engine is set up correctly

   - If you are using database-backed sessions, you have to make sure that `django.contrib.sessions` is in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings 
     and that migrations have run.

Comment: Hey 2ps, I have those 1. and 2. installed already :/. Sorry I should have included this in my initial description.

Comment: Have you already checked your database for the `django_session` table?

Comment: Been looking up how to do this for a while now but struggling. How do I do this? Sorry for the lamen question.

Comment: We’re all laymen here, but all you have to do is type in `python manage.py dbshell` and it will give you access to the shell prompt for your database.  If you’re using mysql or postgres you can type in a sql query to look for the django_sessions table: `show tables like '%session%'` in mysql.

Comment: Hmm. It seems that the problem is that my view that is entering the object into sessions doesn't finish before I call the other view. The solution, I suppose, is to break up the view into two. That said the new challenge is that my object is not pickle-able (maybe because it connects to a simulator over tcp). How can I make it pockleable or find and alternate way to pass it between views?